# Cannot generate correct links

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core

I have the following code in a razor page:

```
@Url.Action("ArticleDetails", "Information", new { slug = article.Slug })
```

The page url where this code is placed has the form of `http://localhost/category/6/category-name` where `6` is the ID of the category

In the `InformationController` I have the following actions:

```
[HttpGet("article/{id}/{slug}")]
public IActionResult ArticleDetails(int id, string slug)
{
    // some code ...

    return View(data);
}

[HttpGet("article/{slug}")]
public IActionResult ArticleDetails(string slug)
{
    // some code ...

    return View(data);
}
```

How can I reach URL of form `article/article-slug` because `@Url.Action(...)` that I have in the page always try to reach controller action with id even if ID is not supplied as an anonymous type.

Links take the form of `article/6/article-slug` instead I want them to be `article/article-slug` without removing action with id in the controller.

I have noticed that **6** is from the id of the category. Also if I delete the controller action with Id i get the correct format of URL.

Comment: `article/6/article-slug` will invoke `ArticleDetails(int id, string slug)`. `article/article-slug` will invoke `ArticleDetails(string slug)`. Could you elaborate more on what you are hoping to achieve?

Comment: @Win I can't generate links of form `article/article-slug`. I know what you are saying. Links get generated as `article/id/article-slug`

Comment: `@Url.Action("ArticleDetails", "Article", new { slug="sample" })` generates `http://localhost:64522/article/sample`. `@Url.Action("ArticleDetails", "Article", new { id=6, slug="sample" })` generates `http://localhost:64522/article/6/sample`. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When resolving the action you're linking to, the `IUrlHelper` instance is using the current value of `id` in your current route (http://localhost/category/6/category-name), which has a value of `6`, as you stated in your OP. Because there exists an `ArticleDetails` action that takes both an `id` and a `slug` (which you provide explicitly), the `ArticleDetails` action that takes both of these parameters is selected.

In order to resolve this, there are a couple of options. The first option is to clear out the `RouteData` value once you've used it in the action invoked when reaching http://localhost/category/6/category-name. In order to do that, you can use the following code within said action:

```
RouteData.Values.Remove("id");
```

I'm not a fan of doing it this way, but it does work. IMO, a better approach would be to simply use different names for the `id` parameter: e.g. `categoryId` and `articleId` in the respective controllers. This both fixes your issue and makes the code more readable in the corresponding actions. Your `ArticleDetails` action would simply change to:

```
[HttpGet("article/{articleId}/{slug}")]
public IActionResult ArticleDetails(int articleId, string slug)
{
    // some code ...

    return View(data);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was exactly what I should know.
What disadvantage have the use of `RouteData.Values.Remove("id");`?

Comment: The main downside is the explicit knowledge that there is an `id` value that lives in `RouteData` specifically. This means, for example, if you were to change the name `id` to something else, you'd have to also change this line to match the new name. I don't think it's a big deal for something like `id`, but it's something to be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Routing can be finicky when trying to do overloads like this. Your best bet is to use named routes:

```
[HttpGet("article/{id}/{slug}", Name = "ArticleDetailsIdSlug")]
public IActionResult ArticleDetails(int id, string slug)

[HttpGet("article/{slug}", Name = "ArticleDetailsSlug")]
public IActionResult ArticleDetails(string slug)
```

Then, in your view:

```
@Url.RouteUrl("ArticleDetailsSlug", new { slug = article.Slug })
```

Now, the routing framework doesn't have to try to figure out which route you actually want (and guess incorrectly apparently), as you'd told it exactly which route to use.